# Eclipse - makros/key replacement?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, editor

In my previous IDE which I used for my website's files there was a very useful option to configure key replacements. Particularly I would like to make sure that extended characters which are to be printed on the web page are added in their respective HTML-code and not as UTF-8 characters or so, because only then I'm on the safe side that the display is proper. So, that old IDE used to put `&auml;` into the text where I entered "ä", and so on.

Is there a way to do this in Eclipse as well? I found that many things are configurable, but I didn't find anything like this key replacement. It's kind of a makro thing, but not really, and is only needed within the editor.

Thanks for any suggestions/help.

Comment: I use [AnyEdit Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) for that: select and Ctrl+Alt+E.

Comment: Thank you. I installed it and was then first wondering, how it works. I need to highlight the text in which the convertable characters are, then it works. Nice! Thank you again!

Comment: Well, I just realised that this isn't working so well. The text has typically a lot of HTML tags in it, and AnyEdit Tools just turns the < and > into &lt; and &gt; which is right but not at all desired. So I have to highlight all the text pieces in between the HTML tags in order to do the transformation. That's as good as typing the HTML entities myself. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The [**AnyEdit Tools**](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) plug-in can be used to convert special characters and umlauts into HTML entities:

Select the text to convert and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or right-click and choose *Convert > Chars to Html Entities*)

Comment: See my comment above. This works only if there are no HTML tags within the text. Since there are (in my case) usually quite a lot, this doesn't really help.

Comment: So you want to exclude `<`, `>` and `"` from being converted, right? Would be an [Ant build script as project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm) that does the converting on save an option for you?

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks for the hint.